# Group sub arrays by key

Tags: php

I have this array.
The keys 141, 143, 148, 163 are id's of teachers in an app.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [141] => 
            [143] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Youcef
                    [userId] => 53
                    [email] => you@gmail.com
                    [mark] => 241
                )
            [148] => 
            [163] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [141] => 
            [143] => Array
                (
                    [name] => John
                    [userId] => 9
                    [email] => teacher@mailinator.com
                    [mark] => 1409
                )

            [148] => 
            [163] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [141] => 
            [143] => 

            [148] => Array
                (
                    [name] => John
                    [userId] => 9
                    [email] => teacher@mailinator.com
                    [mark] => 1409
                )

            [148] => 
            [163] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [141] => 
            [143] => 
            [148] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Abdul-sami
                    [userId] => 1
                    [email] => test1@test.com
                    [mark] => 1680
                )

            [163] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [141] => 
            [143] => 
            [148] => 

            [163] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Rayyan
                    [userId] => 2
                    [email] => rayyan@mailinator.com
                    [mark] => 10861
                )

        )

)
```

I want to merge the sub arrays that have the same key to have something like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [141] => 
            [143] => Array
                ( [0] =>
                (
                    [name] => Youcef
                    [userId] => 53
                    [email] => you@gmail.com
                    [mark] => 241
                )
                  [1] => 
                  (
                   [name] => John
                    [userId] => 9
                    [email] => teacher@mailinator.com
                    [mark] => 1409
                  )
                )
            [148] => 
            [163] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [141] => 
            [143] => 

            [148] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
                    (
                    [name] => John
                    [userId] => 9
                    [email] => teacher@mailinator.com
                    [mark] => 1409
                    )
                    [1] =>
                    (
                    [name] => Abdul-sami
                    [userId] => 1
                    [email] => test1@test.com
                    [mark] => 1680
                    )
                )

            [148] => 
            [163] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [141] => 
            [143] => 
            [148] => 

            [163] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Rayyan
                    [userId] => 2
                    [email] => rayyan@mailinator.com
                    [mark] => 10861
                )

        )

)
```

Is there a way to sort the sub arrays by mark Descending ?

Comment: Please, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why do results for teacher 143 appear in element 0 of your merged array, while results for teacher 148 appear in element 1? On the face of it you should create an array indexed by teacher ID and merge the results into that. Sorting the result is straightforward: use `usort()` and sort on whatever, you like.

Comment: Thank you well I'm really new to PHP I have already posted a question and there were no helpful answers. This data is fetched from sql tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand completely your criteria to merge the subarrays. I think that this code could be useful for you:

```
//$array is your input array.

$res = array(); //Result array.

foreach($array as $subarray) {
    foreach($subarray as $key => $value) {
        if(! array_key_exists($key, $res)) {
            $res[$key] = null;
        }

        if(! is_null($value)) {
            if(is_array($res[$key])) {
                $res[$key][] = $value;
            } else {
                $res[$key] = array($value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output (var_dump($res)):

```
array (size=4)
  141 => null
  143 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'Youcef' (length=6)
          'userId' => int 53
          'email' => string 'you@gmail.com' (length=13)
          'mark' => int 241
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'John' (length=4)
          'userId' => int 9
          'email' => string 'teacher@mailinator.com' (length=22)
          'mark' => int 1409
  148 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'John' (length=4)
          'userId' => int 9
          'email' => string 'teacher@mailinator.com' (length=22)
          'mark' => int 1409
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'Abdul-sami' (length=10)
          'userId' => int 1
          'email' => string 'test1@test.com' (length=14)
          'mark' => int 1680
  163 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'Rayyan' (length=6)
          'userId' => int 2
          'email' => string 'rayyan@mailinator.com' (length=21)
          'mark' => int 10861
```